# Custom abort mapping/exceptions in Flask

Tags: python, exception, flask, werkzeug, httpexception

The default message for Flask `400` exception (`abort()`) is:

```
{
  "message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."
}
```

For `404`:

```
{
  "message": "The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. You have requested this URI [/obj/] but did you mean /obj/ or /obj/<int:id>/ or /obj/<int:id>/kill/ ?"
}
```

I have trouble comprehending these messages when I'm getting them as replies in my API (especially the first one, I thought there's something wrong with encryption or headers) and I thing it's kinda tiresome to try to override text manually for every `abort()` exception. So I change the mapping:

```
from flask import abort
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException


class BadRequest(HTTPException):
    code = 400
    description = 'Bad request.'


class NotFound(HTTPException):
    code = 404
    description = 'Resource not found.'


abort.mapping.update({
    400: BadRequest,
    404: NotFound
})
```

For the case of `400` it works beautifully. But when it comes to `404` it is still the same message. I tested it in the same place in my code - it works for `abort(400)`, `abort(403)` and some of the others, but it gets mysteriously overridden by default message on `abort(404)`. Debugging didn't help much. What may be the culprit here?

**Update**. Yes, I'm using `abort` imported from `flask` not `flask_restful` as the latter doesn't have the mapping and it's a function not an `Aborter` object. Besides, it does work for most exceptions, so it's probably not the real issue here.

**Update 2**. The `abort.mapping` seems to be perfectly fine on execution. The exceptions in question are overridden, including `404`.
[image: Proofpic]

<strike>**Update 3**: I've put together a little sandbox, that I use for debugging.</strike> (removed the repo since the mystery is long solved).

Comment: Flask/Werkzeug maintainer here, please don't recommend using `abort.mapping` because that attribute is not a public API. `abort` is documented as a function, and with Werkzeug 0.12 this code actually doesn't work anymore. We just got a bugreport that implies that we broke our public API here.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer but what is the preferred way to override all the original errors and messages in one place?

Comment: There currently is none I admit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It took me some time, but now I actually found the place, where it all derails on `404` error. It's actually an undocumented feature in flask-restful. Look at [the code](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/0.3.3/flask_restful/__init__.py#L302) here. Whatever message you chose persists until that very place and then it becomes the default. What we need now is just put `ERROR_404_HELP = False` to our config and everything works as intended.

Why is this code even there in the first place? OK, perhaps, I can live with that, but it should be all over the documentation. Even when I googled the name of the constant, I only got a couple of GitHub issues ([1](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/181), [2](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/449)).

Anyways, the mystery is officially solved.

Answer (score 2):

By the way... I can't point to documentation for how I discovered this, I just tried it (that's how I learn most development!) but, you can simply abort with the desired response code but instead return a custom string with it. I think this makes sense because you're using the framework the way it's intended, you're not writing tons of code, you're returning the correct response code and in the fashion the framework expects, and you're informing any human who reads it as to the application's context for the error.

```
from flask import abort

abort(404, "And here's why.")
```

Comment: I'm aware of this option. It's usually not a very good idea to make these messages too informative, especially in case of closed, commercial project. Also it's tiresome to override it in every case.